# Validar número de móvil y número de teléfono fija de número españoles en Android

Tags: java, android, regex, validación

Necesito hacer 2 funciones, una que me valide si un dato introducido es un número de móvil español y otro que me valide si se trata de un número de teléfono español, ya sea móvil o fijo.

De momento tengo estas 2 funciones pero no sé si son correctas:

```
private static boolean validarMovilER(String movil) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\+34|0034|34)?[6|7|9][0-9]{8}$");
    return pattern.matcher(movil).matches();
}

private static boolean validarMovilP(String movil) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.PHONE;
    return pattern.matcher(movil).matches();
}
```

Comment: puedes usar nuevamente una expresión regular :p

Comment: Dentro de una clase de caracteres (corchetes), no hay que usar `|`s a menos que también se quiera coincidir con ese caracter. `\+` -> `\\+` y `[6|7|9]` -> `[679]`... aunque viendo la respuesta, parece que el 8 también es válido.

Comment: No es exactamente lo mismo porque yo uso también telefonos fijos @Mariano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los teléfonos en España, pueden empezar por 6 ó 7 si son móviles y por 8 ó 9, si son fijos. Así que puedes usar una misma expresión regular para validar el teléfono

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\+34|0034|34)?[6789]\d{8}$");
```

Partiendo los prefijos para cada tipo de teléfono, puedes crear dos expresiones regulares, una para fijos y otra para móviles

**Para Fijos**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\+34|0034|34)?[89]\d{8}$");
```

**Para móviles**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\+34|0034|34)?[67]\d{8}$");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me da error la expresión regular. Si lo pongo asi: `Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("^(\\+34|0034|34)?[89]{8}$");` no me da error, pero nose si es la forma correcta

Comment: Donde esta dando el error?, al comprobar la expresión regular si que me esta devolviendo valores correctos en mi prueba

Comment: Me sale este errior antes de ejecutar el código: `Illegal escape character in string literal`

Comment: Se me ocurre que cambies `\d{8}` por `[0-9]{8}$`

Comment: @AlbertoMier Sí, es la forma correcta. Todas las barras en Java hay que escaparlas 2 veces. Además, no es necesario crear un grupo que después no se va a usar, por lo que conviene usar `"^(?:(?:\\+|00)?34)?[89]\\d{8}$"`